# how to solve the ptrace_scope on mac

Tags: java, macos, jvm, jmap

I'm using mac os 10.13.2

When I execute jmap I got an error:

```
➜  ~ jps
34819
35626 Launcher
35627 DataportalApplication
35899 Jps
➜  ~ ps -efj 35627
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD              USER  PGID   SESS JOBC STAT   TT
  501 35627 34819   0  3:16下午 ??         0:09.48 /Library/Java/Ja mac  34819      0    1 S      ??
➜  ~ su mac
Password:
➜  ~ jmap -heap 35627
Attaching to process ID 35627, please wait...
Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach symbolicator to the process
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach symbolicator to the process
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal$BsdDebuggerLocalWorkerThread.execute(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:169)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal.attach(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:287)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attachDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:671)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebuggerDarwin(HotSpotAgent.java:659)
```

So many Dalao said that `su`'d to the correct user having the relevant permissions the issue went away.
I tried like this,but it didn't work.